# Using a class inside a dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, class, dll, export

I have a class inside a dll which I want to use in another project. I read [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL) about how to do this and my pseudo code looks like this

**interface.h**

```
#ifdef  EXPORT
#define SOMEAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define SOMEAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

struct ISomeInterface
{
  virtual void SomeMethod()=0;
};

typedef ISomeInterface* SOMEHANDLE;

#define EXTERN_C     extern "C"

EXTERN_C SOMEAPI SOMEHANDLE WINAPI CreateSomething(VOID);
```

And then I have `SomeDLL.dll` which implements `ISomeInterface` and `CreateSomething`.
When I try to use this in my client I get linker error. The client looks like this:
**Client.cpp**

```
#include "interface.h"
SOMEHANDLE h = ::CreateSomething();  // Linker error here: Unresolved external
```

I can solve this by adding the dll project as a dependency of Client project in VC++. Then everything is good.
The problem is what if I want to use this a standalong dll(which is the case right now)? How do I get rid of the linker error then?

Comment: You may need to provide a static lib, that allows loading the dll at runtime and wraps the interface for your client. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360828/plugin-pattern-with-dll-how-can-i-extract-plugin-interface-from-dll)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I can solve this by adding the dll project as a dependency of Client project

Yes, that automatically does the one thing you have to do in a stand-alone project by hand.  Project + Properties, Linker, Input, Additional Dependencies setting.  Add the .lib file that was generated by the DLL project.  The import library, it tells the linker about the functions exported by the DLL.

Comment: Thank you. I managed to solve this problem by adding `#pragma comment(lib, "FormatDriveDLL.lib")`. But you're doing this automatically.